# passing a named variable as a command line argument to a perl script

Tags: perl

`awk` offers a convenient way to pass named variables to a script using the `-v` flag (e.g., `awk -v var="value" ...`), a facility that is quite useful when composing ad hoc scripts. Can the same be done with Perl or does one need to resort to `argv`, `getopts`, `%ENV`, interpolation by the shell through appropriate quoting, etc.? The `-s` option can give the desired effect but is limited to boolean values.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't take it as a positional argument?

Comment: I certainly could, but was just wondering if it could be given a name.

Comment: You'll find that in general programming languages don't allow that.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it wasn't possible, but wanted to be sure. It would be convenient for one-off uses.. of course positional parameters would work as well in such a case

Comment: `-s` is not limited to boolean. Eg `-s -xyz=abc` and `print $xyz\n"`. From the man page, `perldoc perlrun`.

Comment: @meuh: Thanks, I misunderstood the -s option, thinking it merely allowed setting switches. You could make your comment an answer. Could you clarify the correct use: e.g., `perl -s -xyz=abc -e 'print "xyz=$xyz\n"'` gives the error "No Perl script found in input"

Comment: I got the same thing too. It doesnt seem to be useful for your "oneliner" use case. You need a file with `#!/usr/bin/perl -s` in it for it to work!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to `meuh` for pointing out the use of the `-s` option for the purpose of passing arbitrary data as opposed to simply toggling switches; after further investigation, the correct syntax for one-liner use of the `-s` option turned out to be the following:

```
$ perl -se 'print "xyz=$xyz\n"' -- -xyz="abc"
xyz=abc
```

Answer (score 0):

The following demonstrates reading awk-like variable assignments from the command-line as well as accepting in-line perl code in a shell script:

```
# cat test.sh
perl - FS=':' GRP='50' <<'EOF'
eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
print "$FS\n";
print "$GRP\n";
EOF
```

This is the proof:

```
# sh test.sh
:
50
```

And here is an alternative form of the OP's answer that accepts inline, multi-line perl code:

```
# cat test.sh
perl -s -- - -xyz="abc" <<'EOF'
print "xyz=$xyz\n";
EOF
```

And the proof:

```
# sh xyz.sh
xyz=abc
```

This format looks very similar to `awk` written in a shell script, and makes it easy to replace translated non-trivial `awk` code with `a2p` generated `perl` code without having to resort to putting the code in a separate file.